# C# Windows service - zombie process after stopping

Tags: c#, service, ssh, zombie-process

I'm write Windows Service on C# (.NET Framework 4.5).
After stopping the service him process becomes a zombie-process (He don't kill by "taskkill").

[image]

It ends in about 3-15 minutes: The longer the service works, the longer the process finished. In debug service correct ending and exit from all visible code.

In work I'm execute remote commands by SSH. 
I noticed that the execution such teams - perhaps the reason zombies.
Because after work without having to run the commands, the process is terminated immediately.

For execute SSH-commands I'n use SSH.NET (http://sshnet.codeplex.com/):

```
public class RenciSSHExecute:ISSHExecutable 
{
    public string Execute(String host, String user, String password, String command)
    {
        string result = String.Empty;
        Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
        try
        {
            using (var client = new Renci.SshNet.SshClient(host, user, password))
            {
                client.Connect();
                Logger.Information("Send SSH command [{0}]: {1}.", guid.ToString(), command);
                var cmd = client.RunCommand(command);
                result = cmd.Result.Replace("\n", "");
                Logger.Information("Result SSH command [{0}]: {1}", guid.ToString(), result);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception(String.Format("Failed execution ssh-command: {0} on {1}@{2}. Error message: {2}",
                command, user, host, e.Message));
        }      

        return result;
    }
}
```

What is the cause of zombies and how to fix it?

**UPDATE:**

I use **"Windows Resource Monitor"**:
[image]
In the section "Assotsiated Handles" I found rows:

```
\Device\Mup\$COMPUTERNAME\PIPE\winreg
```

And these are the **$COMPUTERNAME** already disconnected machines, which the interaction is completed.

What are these lines? Could this be the cause of zombie-process?

In code of service I use Process.GetProcesses for getting list of running process on remote mashine:

```
var remoteProcesses = Process.GetProcesses(remote_client_name);
```

Could **Process.GetProcesses** leave some resources not closed if the machine is switched off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Practical way has been revealed that the cause of zombie-process were calls:

```
var remoteProcesses = Process.GetProcesses(remote_client_name);
```

In my service it is necessary for check the running processes on the remote machine before shutdown it.

Apparently "GetProcesses()" uses pipe-channels for sending the request and does not have time to close them properly before shutdown the machine.

Anyway, after eliminating its from code of service has become disconnected immediately.